# Creating new collection and document with Firestore REST API returning HTTP 400

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am using Firestore and not Realtime database for a test project I am working on.

- As a starter, I am trying to create a new document inside an existing collection and project which I manually created through the web interface. My project id is `newproject-30f72` and the already created collection name is `testcollection`.
- I have enabled the `Email/Password` authentication method, and I have registered a new `email-id/password` user. The rule I have for auth enabled write is as follows.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

At this point, I am not sure, a barer token alone passed in the header is enough to validate the `request.auth.uid != null`, so most probably my rule could also be wrong, as I was using the simulator to auto generate the rule, but I verified that the rule is not causing the problem I am facing at the moment by disabling the rule completely.

- I have enabled `rules` so that only authenticated users can write to firestore. (and by authentication, I mean the `idToken` for a specific `email/password` based user and not the `apiKey` for a web app. I don't know if this is possible though.)
- I have enabled the `Add Firebase to your web app / register app` and that gave me a json object named `firebaseConfig` with the following details.

```
   var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "some_api_key",
      authDomain: "newproject-30f72.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://newproject-30f72.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "newproject-30f72",
      storageBucket: "newproject-30f72.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "111122223333",
      appId: "1:1111:web:2222"
   };
```

I am using the `apiKey` from the above json object to get an `idToken` valid for some time, to write to the firestore database. The code for that is as below in python3.

```py
import json
from urllib import request, error
from collections import defaultdict

firebase_apikey = 'some_api_key'
auth_request_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key={}".format(firebase_apikey)

class auth:
    def __init__(self, email: str, password: str):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.post_data = defaultdict()
        self.post_data['email'] = self.email
        self.post_data['password'] = self.password
        self.post_data['returnSecureToken'] = True
        self.headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        # print("POST DATA IS:: " + json.dumps(self.post_data))
        self.r = request.Request(auth_request_url,
                                 data=json.dumps(self.post_data).encode(),
                                 headers=self.headers)
        # self.url_open

    def get_auth_token(self):
        try:
            self.url_open = request.urlopen(self.r)
        except Exception as e:
            return e
        try:
            return json.loads(self.url_open.read())
        except Exception as e:
            return e


s = auth("someuser.somethingelse@gmail.com", "somepassword")
response = s.get_auth_token()
id_token = response['idToken']
expires_in = response['expiresIn']
```

I got the idToken which is a 924 character long string.

Now I am trying to write to firestore with the `idToken` that I received and valid for 3600(seconds I presume) using the `Authorization': 'Bearer` header as follows.

```py
firestore_project_url = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{}/databases/(default)/documents:write".format(
    'newproject-30f72')

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % id_token,
}

test_data = '''
{
    "writes": [{
        "updateMask": {
            "fieldPaths": ["name"]
        },
        "update": {
            "name": "projects/newproject-30f72/databases/(default)/documents/testcollection/testdoc/",
            "fields": {
                "name": {
                    "stringValue": "test"
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
'''

test_data_json_bytes = json.dumps(test_data).encode("utf-8")
req = request.Request(url=firestore_project_url,
                      data=test_data_json_bytes,
                      headers=headers,
                      method='POST')
print(headers)
f = request.urlopen(req)
```

I can see the headers as

```
{'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsI........<snip>'}
```

but I am getting a `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` error.

I was referring to [Firebase Firestore REST example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762667/firebase-firestore-rest-example) to check it using curl with custom headers to add the bearer token and to see if there is any possible verbosity, and I am seeing

```
*   Trying 74.125.68.95...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to firestore.googleapis.com (74.125.68.95) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.googleapis.com
*  start date: May 14 13:35:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  6 13:20:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "firestore.googleapis.com" matched cert's "*.googleapis.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x560e5884af30)
> POST /v1beta1/projects/newproject-30f72/databases/(default)/documents/testcollection3 HTTP/2
> Host: firestore.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> {Content-type: application/json, Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6........<snip>}
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 258
> 
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 400 
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< referrer-policy: no-referrer
< content-length: 1555
< date: Fri, 31 May 2019 14:31:36 GMT
< 
* HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
* stopped the pause stream!
* Connection #0 to host firestore.googleapis.com left intact
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
* Closing connection 0
```

I was referring to the following links for references.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/4Le2RskC3cg
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/commit

What I am trying to achieve is

- use the email/password auth to get authenticated to firestore
- create collection and write docs to it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Any reason you're not using firebase-admin?

Comment: I am fine with using firebase-admin too, but I couldn't find a documentation reference for signing in with idToken using emailid/password authentication (not with oauth or the json key file). Any reference or sample code to authentication and further CRUD operation is greatly appreciated. Thank you @Will

Comment: Well, if client passes you idToken then use [Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). If you client gives you email/password then use [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password). I've used the latter.

Comment: @Will Please correct me if I am wrong, I am using the REST API itself now, where the payload sets `returnSecureToken` to `True` and it returns an idToken. I am stuck from that point. I cannot find a doc that says how to use that idToken. Can you kindly point me to any docs or a reference that you've used, or a github repo, or a sample snippet that I can use as a reference? Thank you very much.

Comment: ah, apologies for not understanding the question properly. You want Firestore to kick its rules in because you're basically impersonating a user?

Comment: OK, I've tested a GET using `Authorization: Bearer <idtoken>` and it works fine. A 400 error implies something on your body is wonky. Have you tested that a simple GET on a collection works with auth passed the way you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO this is what worked for me (I used `requests` module but net effect is the same)

First the Auth, exactly as you do.

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + API_KEY
payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
rsp = requests.post(url, data=payload)
id_token = rsp.json().get("idToken")

# User idToken from your auth for later requests
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': "Bearer %s" % id_token
}
```

Now create a document in a collection

```
# Create a doc in "testcoll"
url = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/" + PROJECT + "/databases/(default)/documents/testcoll"
payload = {
  "fields": {
    "meaningOfLife": {"integerValue": 42}
  }
}
# Create Doc
rsp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(payload))
assert(rsp.status_code == 200)
docref = rsp.json().get("name")
print(rsp.json())
```

Now update the same document

```
# Update doc
url = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + docref
payload = {
  "fields": {
    "meaningOfLife": {"stringValue": '43'}
  }
}
rsp = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(payload))
assert(rsp.status_code == 200)
print(rsp.json())
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Will. You are a life saver. This worked.

Comment: I'm glad I worked through it because I wasn't sure at the time if the idToken could be passed in REST calls. The SDKs and libraries don't support this at the moment.